# cocoa - Edit/Design NSView visually

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoa, nsview

How can I visually design a NSView in Xcode? I'm trying to build a statusBar app with a statusMenu only

[image: Menu Custom View]

As you can see above, the object appear but I can't edit it visually, then it go like this as a result:

[image: Result using Storyboard only]

I attempted to use a XIB file (only have a NSView, no ViewController), but I can't put the NSView in the XIB into the AppDelegate. I tried another ways and managed to use the XIB file, but then I can't use the Storyboard.

Do you have any idea for this situation?

UPDATE

Thank Max for answer my question. I actually tried that before but failed. I tried it again after your comment and there's still no luck. Here is how I did
[image: Tried]

I created a ViewController then I change its view to the MenuCustomView (NSView)
This is the code in AppDelegate

```
    let statusBar = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar().statusItemWithLength(-1)
var menuCustomView = NSView()

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    let statusIcon = NSImage(named: "statusIcon")
    let statusMenu = NSMenu()
    statusBar.image = statusIcon
    statusBar.menu = statusMenu

    let menuItem = NSMenuItem()
    menuItem.title = "title"
    var vc = ViewController()
    menuCustomView = vc.view
    menuItem.view = menuCustomView
    statusMenu.addItem(menuItem)

}
```

Files I have in the project

[image: Files I have]

Comment: If you have only one view, why do you need the storyboard?

Comment: I may have others in the further development, I don't want to be limited. And I prefer Storyboard, it's neat. So if there's any way to use Storyboard as a main interface designing tool, it would be better.

Comment: Ok, I'll post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you don't need the view controller, you can use them to design the views. Create one in the storyboard, edit the view the way you want.

Then you can use the view by creating a viewController out of the storyboard and using its view property to attach the view to the `NSStatusBarItem`

My words in code:

```
    let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("MyViewController") as! NSViewController
    let view = viewController.view
```

I assume you want to add functioning code to the view. To, for example respond to the button click, you have to subclass the NSViewController and then implement the code you would have added to the AppDelegate.

If you need any more explanation, feel free to write me :)

Comment: I updated the question after tried (again) with you idea. Still not working. Please help me more. Thank a lot

Comment: Edited my answer, hope I can help you!

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much, Max! The only thing left is that I don't understand why I can just instantiate controller by making a new instance of if with "let vc = ViewController()"?

Comment: Can you answer my question above? What is the difference?

Comment: Sure! Creating a empty viewController with ViewController() won't contain the view you have set up in IB, because there is no relation to the one created. To access this view, you have load the viewController from the storyboard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79354/discussion-between-blues-and-max).